# QGIS XYZ to 3D coloured contoured surface

Tags: qgis, contour, xyz, surface

I am using QGIS. I have XYZ data in a CSV file. I want to show it as a 3D surface that is contoured (every 10’) and is coloured between contours.  The z data is below sea level so negative. I can interpolate with TIN and then contour but it just doesn’t look good and no colours. Also the data takes it back to zero depth around the edges, how do I limit it to just the negative depths?